# How to calculate values of the Hahn-Banach-extended integral functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Phi: C[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the linear functional
defined by $\Phi(f)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. Let $\tilde{\Phi}$ an extension
of $\Phi$ to the normed space $(B[0,1]$ (of bounded functions on
$[0,1]$, with the $\sup$ norm) such that $\|\Phi\|=\|\tilde{\Phi}\|$.
Such an extension is guaranteed by the Hahn-Banach theorem. Let $h(x)$
be as follows: $h(x)=1$ if $x\leq 1/2$ and $h(x)=-1$ if $x>1/2$.

How to ***calculate*** $\tilde{\Phi}(h)$? My difficulty is that it is
impossible to approximate $h$ uniformly by continuous function.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to calculate $\tilde\Phi$ until you've chosen a specific extension of $\Phi$, of which there are infinitely many. So which extension are you using?

Comment: That's the thing about Axiom of Choice.  you get the existence of a whole lot of items, but not a recipe to compute any one of them.

Comment: @GEdgar But, the lebesgue integral would be one such extension, right?

Comment: Lebesgue integral is not defined for many bounded funtions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular example.

Consider the extension obtained by adding just one more function.  Namely adding your function $h$ to $C[0,1]$.  If you are reading the correct proof of the HB theorem, it shows what the possible values of the extension are.  There is a certain interval, and we may choose any number in that interval as the value.

Here, the interval we compute is $[-1,1]$.